# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - org.apache.commons, tomcat 7

Tags: java, class, jsp, servlets, file-upload

I am trying to run a servlet fileupload example in tomcat 7 which is based on org.apache.commons.fileupload

i complied servlet class file in CMD (Win 7 64bit) by using this command.

```
 C:\Users\Preet\Desktop>javac -cp .;E:/servlet-api.jar;"C:\Program Files\Apache S
oftware Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\sim\WEB-INF\lib\commons-fileupload-1.2.2.j
ar" "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\sim\WEB-INF\
classes\SimpleServlets.java"
```

Everything was fine.

After compiling i tried my example i got a error which is

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(ServletFileUpload.java:68)
    SimpleServlets.doPost(SimpleServlets.java:21)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

then at last googling, found few solution and i followed them one by one.

1.Made a lib folder in WEB-INF and copied commons-fileupload-1.2.2 and commons-io-2.2.
But no luck.

2.Copied commons-fileupload-1.2.2 and commons-io-2.2 in tomcat/lib.
But no luck.

3.Add commons-fileupload-1.2.2 and commons-io-2.2 to classpaath but no luck.

Please tell me what is wrong.

My code

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class SimpleServlets extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3208409086358916855L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

        if (isMultipart) {
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

            try {
                List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();

                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                        String fileName = item.getName();

                        String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                        File path = new File(root + "/uploads");
                        if (!path.exists()) {
                            boolean status = path.mkdirs();
                        }

                        File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
                        System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        item.write(uploadedFile);
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404791/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-http-httpservletrequest)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`, which is present in the servlet-api.jar. That's the one you need to include in your deployed solution.

Check out [findjar.com](http://findjar.com/class/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), which will tell you which jars contain given classes. It doesn't help you resolve required version numbers, but it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: But another servlet Form example is working fine which is without file uplading features, but contain import javax.servlet.http.*;