# the command "grails run-war" throws Error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, grails

I'm using Eclipse STS 3.2.0. This is what I did so far:

1. grails run-app command works
2. grails war command works
3. I run Tomcat separately, and deploy the generated war though the Tomcat. I also paste the errors (after the STS errors report).
4. I have to use Maven, so I executed the command "grails create-pom",
   and I added "pom true" as described here:
   http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/create-pom.html

   - I tried both with Maven (adding the line "pom true") and without (commenting the line "pom true")
5. I deleted the folders: "C:\Users\ch.grails\ivy-cache", "project\target", run the command "grails clean", and "grails run-war" again, with the same error result.

A) This is the full error report of STS:

```
    | Environment set to development.....
    | Packaging Grails application....
    | Compiling 22 source files.....
    | Error 2013-05-16 18:50:20,674 [main] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - This class is not an ArtefactHandler:org.grails.plugin.resources.artefacts.ResourceMapperArtefactHandler
    | Error 2013-05-16 18:50:20,678 [main] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - This class is not an ArtefactHandler:org.grails.plugin.resources.artefacts.ResourcesArtefactHandler
    | Error 2013-05-16 18:50:20,718 [main] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - This class is not an ArtefactHandler:grails.plugin.cache.CacheConfigArtefactHandler
    | Compiling 3 GSP files for package [alojamiento]..
    | Compiling 4 GSP files for package [databaseMigration]..
    | Building WAR file.....
    | Done creating WAR target\Alojamiento-0.1.war
    | Error java.lang.NullPointerException
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    | Error     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    (...)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:768)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:566)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:465)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:416)
    | Error     at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.executeCommand(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:144)
    | Error     at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run(GrailsProcess.java:126)
    | Error     at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main(GrailsProcess.java:89)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    | Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
    | Error Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.createGroovyObjectGetPropertySite(AbstractCallSite.java:254)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.acceptGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:239)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    | Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.TomcatServer.<init>(TomcatServer.groovy:58)
    | Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.IsolatedWarTomcatServer.<init>(IsolatedWarTomcatServer.groovy:35)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    | Error     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    | Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.TomcatServerFactory.createForWAR(TomcatServerFactory.groovy:88)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.container.GrailsProjectRunner.runWarInternal(GrailsProjectRunner.groovy:151)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.container.GrailsProjectRunner.runWar(GrailsProjectRunner.groovy:96)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.container.GrailsProjectRunner$runWar.call(Unknown Source)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    (...)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    | Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    | Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    | Error     at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    | Error     ... 76 more
```

B) Error report of Tomcat console ALREADY FIXED (following the answer of @Sérgio Michels):

```
    may 16, 2013 6:57:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
    INFO: Despliegue del archivo D:\Software\IW-apache-tomcat-7.0.37\webapps\Alojami
    ento-0.1.war de la aplicaci¾n web
    may 16, 2013 6:57:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
    2013-05-16 18:57:50,613 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoade
    r  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transact
    ionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org
    .springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with n
    ame 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' whil
    e setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframewor
    k.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFac
    tory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean
    property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.Bea
    nCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocati
    on of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.M
    etaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exceptio
    n is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of cl
    ass 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE'
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
    h name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested
    exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error crea
    ting bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sess
    ionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is or
    g.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
    name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' whi
    le setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.b
    eans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDet
    ector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframewor
    k.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData;
     nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create J
    DBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC
    =TRUE'
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
    ng bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessio
    nFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.
    springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with na
    me 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while
     setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.bea
    ns.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetec
    tor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.
    jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; n
    ested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDB
    C driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=T
    RUE'
    (...)
    INFO: Server startup in 39571 ms
```

**UPDATE:**

C) The new error report of Tomcat console, after the correction of @Sérgio Michels:

```
    INFO: Despliegue del archivo D:\Software\IW-apache-tomcat-7.0.37\webapps\Alojami
    ento-0.1.war de la aplicaci¾n web
    may 16, 2013 10:09:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
    2013-05-16 22:09:20,376 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugi
    n  - This class is not an ArtefactHandler:org.grails.plugin.resources.artefacts.
    ResourceMapperArtefactHandler
    2013-05-16 22:09:20,381 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugi
    n  - This class is not an ArtefactHandler:org.grails.plugin.resources.artefacts.
    ResourcesArtefactHandler
    2013-05-16 22:09:20,429 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugi
    n  - This class is not an ArtefactHandler:grails.plugin.cache.CacheConfigArtefac
    tHandler
    2013-05-16 22:09:27,435 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoade
    r  - Error initializing the application: HttpServletRequest
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HttpServletRequest
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1810)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
    1)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
    java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
    .java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest
            ... 8 more
    2013-05-16 22:09:27,439 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoade
    r  - Error initializing Grails: HttpServletRequest
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HttpServletRequest
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1810)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
    1)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
    java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
    .java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest
            ... 8 more
    may 16, 2013 10:09:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Error listenerStart
    may 16, 2013 10:09:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Fall¾ en arranque del Contexto [/Alojamiento-0.1] debido a errores previ
    os
```

**UPDATE 2**

D) Same fail after running tests!

```
    | Tests FAILED  - view reports in D:\ch\eclipse_workspaces\IW-grails\Alojamiento\target\test-reports
    | Error java.lang.NullPointerException
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    | Error     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404791/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-http-httpservletrequest

Comment: Witch version of Grails and JDK are you using?

Comment: Grails 2.2.2. jdk1.7.0_21

Comment: Can you try with a 1.6 jdk?

Comment: same error, so I return back to the default one (at the propierties of my project): J2SE-1.5 (jdk1.7.0_21)

Comment: J2SE-1.5 is the 1.5 level, and not 1.7. You need to adjust your build path to use 1.6 or 1.7, that's probably the cause of your error.

Comment: J2SE above to 1.5 doesn't appear on the list. It is J2SE1.5(JDK1.7) though. I tried anyway with JavaSE 1.7, JavaSE 1.6 or JDK 1.7 with no luck.

Comment: anyway, it is more important for me this probably related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705243/in-grails-the-command-tomcatdeploy-does-not-generate-the-complete-war-as-the

Comment: and this is probably even more related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705555/the-command-grails-tomcat-deploy-produces-error-java-net-httpretryexception

Answer (score 2):

Your second error occurs because you not defined your datasource correctly:

> Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData;
>        nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create J
>       DBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC
>       =TRUE'

You're using an `h2` jdbc url with the MySQL driver (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver).

If you adjust your `DataSource.groovy` your deployed instance should work.

Comment: You are right. I fixed it and updated the question adding the NEW ERROR at the end :(

The previous error happened because I have the mysql configuration at the development environment, but the command "grails war" uses the production environment. Solution: instead of using "grails war", I should use "grails dev war".

Comment: It deploys in Tomcat now, but the command "grails run-war" still fails with the same reported errors. It worked in Tomcat after: 1) Creating an empty mysql database (Grails generate the tables, but you have to create a database with the same provided name). 2) Make sure the BuildConfig.groovy dependency "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.25" was in the war (I commented the line + dev war + commented out the line.

Comment: Same fail after running tests. I updated the question: UPDATE 2

D) Same fail after running tests!